# Locale URL segment being duplicated, eg https://website.test/en/en/

Tags: localization, craft3, multi-site, segments

## Problem

I have a problem on a local Valet setup: the locale URL segment is appearing twice in URLs.

Eg from a page at URL of `en/about/approach`, `{{ url('about/approach')}}` outputs `https://website.test/en/en/about/approach`

(And you only get the correct URL if outputting this from `/about/approach`)

Guessing I've missed something obvious but no idea what... thanks!

---

## Setup

Base URLs are set to `@web/en/` and `@web/de/`.

In the `web` folder we have two index files, eg `de/index.php` and `en/index.php`

Running `valet which` reports `This site is served by [CraftValetDriver].`

In `general.php` I've got:

```
'test' => [
// Base site URL
'siteUrl' => 'http://website.test'
```

The Entry URI Format for the Pages section is `{parent.slug}/{slug}`

---

## Contents of /web/en/index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Craft www bootstrap file
 */

// Set path constants
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__, 2));
define('CRAFT_SITE', 'english');
define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');

$root = dirname(__DIR__).'/en';

// Load Composer's autoloader
require_once CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/autoload.php';

// Load dotenv?
if (file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(CRAFT_BASE_PATH))->load();
}

// Load and run Craft
define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production');
$app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
$app->run();
```

---

## Contents of /web/index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Craft web bootstrap file
 */

// Set path constants
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');

// Load Composer's autoloader
require_once CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/autoload.php';

// Load dotenv?
if (file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(CRAFT_BASE_PATH))->load();
}

// Load and run Craft
define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production');
$app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that the `@web` alias resolves to this:

> The URL to the folder that contains the **index.php** file that was loaded for the request

Now that you’re serving your English site from web/en/index.php, `@web` will already resolve to http://website.test/en.

The alias `@web/en` you are using for your site’s base URL does therefore resolve to http://website.test/en/en

So you can fix it be using `@web` for your base URLs, or what I would rather recommend is to serve all your sites from a single web/index.php file (which is possible [now in Craft 3](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/8e78482)). With this change `@web` will always refer to http://website.test and you need to use `@web/en` again in your site settings.

Comment: Just a simple question: we usually do that too and I usually recommend others the same because it's the most easiest solution in my opinion. Do you know any disadvantages in having a single `index.php` for all requests rather than having multiple different one?

Comment: @RobinSchambach none that I know of, but I don’t have much experience with it either. I can update my answer when I encounter a situation where dedicated index.php files are needed. But the [auto detection](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/8e78482) seems to work really well!